# SUM of multiple rows of SUMs in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns a `total` column for every `order`:

```
SELECT o.id, o.created, o.status, o.shipping,
SUM(op.price*op.amount*(1+op.tax/100.0))+COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)+COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0) AS total

FROM orders AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_products as op ON o.id=op.order_id
GROUP BY o.id;
```

[image: Output of the first query]

*Output of the query*

Now I want to calculate the total revenue, so that would be the SUM of these `total` columns.

I tried using a subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
SUM(total) FROM (
    SELECT
    SUM(op.price*op.amount*(1+op.tax/100.0))+COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)+COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0) AS total
    FROM orders AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN order_products as op ON o.id=op.order_id
    GROUP BY o.id
) AS foo
;
```

[image: Output of the second query]

*Output of the query*

However:

- The result column was named `SUM(total)`, not `foo`

  - Seems like the `AS foo` is used for the subquery, not for the top-level `SUM()`
- Without the `AS foo`, it doesn't work
- <sub>The result that this query returned might have been incorrect, **but that could have been due to rounding**.</sub>

**How should the query, to SUM multiple rows of SUMs, look?**

*Note: <strike>Those NULL totals **almost** certainly won't exist in production, but it'd still be better to use `COALESCE(x, 0)` just to make sure the query executes correctly.</strike> Seems like this SUM() is fine with NULL values?*

Comment: Your `AS foo` is naming the sub-query *(also known as inline-view)*, not your field.  Try `SUM(total) AS foo` and `FROM (...) AS bar`

Comment: does your 1st query result ok for you?

Comment: @MatBailie That works. I tried `SUM(totals) AS foo` without the `AS bar` and that resulted in an error.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich you need to read about how [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) work in MySQL

Comment: @MatBailie Please write an answer. Unless someone can find a more efficient way, I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to alias name to total you have o set it before from not after your select and for checking null you have to set a value for that:

```
  SELECT 
    SUM(COALESCE(a.total,0)) as foo FROM (
        SELECT
        SUM(op.price*op.amount*(1+op.tax/100.0))+COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)+COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0) AS total
        FROM orders AS o
        LEFT OUTER JOIN order_products as op ON o.id=op.order_id
        GROUP BY o.id
    ) AS a
```

Comment: Use COALESCE(). And indeed, this works, and produces same output as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484817/sum-of-multiple-rows-of-sums-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment91911250_52484817

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes I thought its sql! sorry.

Comment: It does. And this answer seems the simplest.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it answers the *question* (so that anyone who finds this question can get the answer they're looking for). Though I'll personally use MatBailie's code, as it's better for my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  SUM(
     COALESCE(op.order_total, 0)
    +COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
    +COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
  )
    AS grand_total
FROM
  orders   AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    order_id,
    SUM(price*amount*(1+tax/100.0))  AS order_total
  FROM
    order_products
  GROUP BY
    order_id
)
  AS op
    ON o.id=op.order_id
```

***EDIT:***

You've said that :
 - `SUM(x+y+z) / COUNT(op.order_total)` gives `506`
 - `AVG(x+y+z)` gives `532`

This implies to me that some of the `x+y+z` rows are `NULL` when `x` is `NOT NULL`, therefore it appears that `y` or `z` are `NULL`.

As `y` and `z` are `COALESCE(?, 0) * (1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)`, it ***feels like*** `shipping_tax` is sometimes `NULL`.

Try this query...

```
SELECT
  SUM(
     COALESCE(op.order_total, 0)
    +COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
    +COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
  )
    AS grand_total,
  AVG(
     COALESCE(op.order_total, 0)
    +COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
    +COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
  )
    AS grand_average,
  COUNT(
     COALESCE(op.order_total, 0)
    +COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
    +COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)
  )
    AS grand_row_count,
  COUNT(
    *
  )
    AS set_row_count,
  COUNT(
    o.shipping_tax
  )
    AS shipping_tax_row_count,
  AVG(
     COALESCE(op.order_total, 0)
    +(COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)+COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0))
     *COALESCE(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0, 1)
  )
    AS revised_grand_average
FROM
  orders   AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    order_id,
    SUM(price*amount*(1+tax/100.0))  AS order_total
  FROM
    order_products
  GROUP BY
    order_id
)
  AS op
    ON o.id=op.order_id
```

I ***expect*** that...
 - `grand_average   == grand_total / grand_row_count`
 - `set_row_count   >  grand_row_count`
 - `grand_row_count == shipping_tax_row_count`

If so, then the `revised_grand_average` should be useful to you.

If not, then hopefully this gives you a place to start investigating.

Comment: Could you explain how this solution is better than what you suggested in your comment?

Comment: My comment was explaining why your attempt failed, and what to do to fix the syntax errors.  I didn't say it was a good idea, just that it would fix the syntax errors ;)  This answer aggregates just one table before joining it, avoiding the wierd case of `total = SUM() + Scalar + Scalar`; That minimises effort for the RDBMS and makes it easier to read.

Comment: Oh, and it's legal syntax from MySQL 5.7 onwards.  (Yours breaks in newer MySQL)

Comment: Thanks. Can I make an AVG, instead of a SUM, out of this code easily?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - Yes, it should be either the same or easier to do in this format.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it directly answers the question, so others might find that more helpful, but personally I like your answer (just so you know why I didn't accept your answer). Wrapping the SUM in your answer with `AVG()` didn't work, but dividing it by `COUNT(op.order_total)` worked. I expected AVG() to use the aggregate values by passing the SUM() to it, but it took the result of the SUM. Could there be a more efficient way than dividing by `COUNT(op.order_total)`?

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - You haven't actually said what average you want.  The average value of each order, including or excluding shipping costs and payment fees?  The average value of each item in each order?  The weighted average of each item in each order?  etc, etc, etc.  Be specific...  I ***suspect*** you just need to change the `SUM(` on line 2 to `AVG(`, but that's an educated guess until you specify your needs more clearly.

Comment: Good point. I initially meant the average of order values with all fees and taxes, but that might be a matter of user configuration. Though for now, I'll use the average of order values with all fees and taxes. Changing `SUM(` to `AVG(` returns `532`, while `SUM(...)/COUNT(op.order_total)` returns 506.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - That's odd.  `SUM(x) / COUNT(x)` should equal `AVG(x)` because both `COUNT(x)` and `AVG(x)` ignore `NULL`.  You actually have `SUM(x+y+z)/COUNT(x)` giving a lower result than `AVG(x+y+z)` That implies to me that `x+y+z` has more `NULL` values than `COUNT(x)`.  That implies to me that sometimes `o.shipping_tax` is `NULL`.  I'll edit my question with some diagnostics.

Comment: `*COALESCE(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0), 1)` - add missing `(`. Query output: https://imgur.com/a/p3hALXH. If I do `532.6836842105*20/21`, I get around `507`, so it seems like the `COUNT()` counts some nulls. Running `COUNT(op.order_total)` returns 20. For o.shipping, that's 17 and for o.shipping_tax that's 19. https://imgur.com/a/6UYqjRg

Comment: > As y and z are COALESCE(?, 0) * (1+o.shipping_tax/100.0), it feels like shipping_tax is sometimes NULL. --- Thanks for pointing that out, I should wrap all instances of o.shipping_tax with `COALESCE()`

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich - Yes, a NULL shipping_tax causes one row to become `x + y*NULL + z*NULL => x + NULL + NULL => NULL`.  The NULL tax obliterates the whole row.  Which was the compounded by the use of `COUNT(op.order_total)` which was ***not*** being affected by the `NULL` tax.  So you discounted some values in `SUM()` but not in `COUNT()`.  The `COALESCE(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0, 1)` I added to the last calculation fixes that.

Comment: Wrapping all instances of shipping_tax with COALESCE() changed the result of the average to 532. And now your query works perfectly: https://imgur.com/a/mqkSjfc

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery.  Just remove the `GROUP BY` from the original query:

```
SELECT SUM(op.price*op.amount*(1+op.tax/100.0))+COALESCE(o.shipping, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0)+COALESCE(o.payment_fee, 0)*(1+o.shipping_tax/100.0) AS total
FROM orders o LEFT OUTER JOIN
     order_products op
     ON o.id = op.order_id;
```

This will do the calculation over all the rows.  It should be faster than two levels of aggregation.

The result will be in a column called `total`.

Comment: Error: `#1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.o.shipping'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by` I'd ideally like to solve this without changing the SQL mode.